# Batch File for mass rename

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to rename multiple images saved as .png format from

```
frame (1).png
frame (2).png
frame (3).png ...
```

to:

```
frame_1.png
frame_2.png
frame_3.png
```

I am aware of the .bat file given by

```
cd C:\folder
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (frame*.png) do (
set f=%%a
set f=!f:^(=!
set f=!f:^)=!
ren "%%a" "!f!"
)
```

But this only removes the brackets. I do not know how to modify the code so that instead of just removing the brackets I get an underscore.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=() " %%a in ('dir /B frame*.png') do ren "%%a (%%b)%%c" "%%a_%%b%%c"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set f=!f:^(=!
```

becomes

```
set f=!f:^(=_!
```

and include the space if you wish. The formula is !*varname*:*charsequence*=*replacementsequence*!

For no space, use

```
set f=!f: ^(=_!
```

If there may be multiple spaces, use

```
set f=!f: =!
```

as an extra line

Comment: I do not want the space that is my issue. I tried this. But I do not want the space between frame and the underscore